# Can a DFA (Deterministic Finite State Machine) have 1 loop for multiple inputs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

[image: A deterministic state machine example]

For the DFA shown above, is it ok if you can put all those inputs from B into 1 loop?
eg. 1 loop going from B to B, with inputs 2,4,6,8.

And can I put the digits going out of A, into one line?
I say this to reduce clutter.

Or does each input need to be clearly defined like this?

And would the Non-deterministic version of this FSM look the same?

Comment: You can combine all of the transitions from $A$ to $B$ into a single arrow with five labels, and you can combine all of the loops at $B$ into a single loop with four labels. This is supposed to recognize all strings of digits that start with a single odd digit followed by any number of non-zero even digits followed by a single $0$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thankyou for that. Can I also reduce the lines going from A, into 1 line?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I was suggesting, just as in **HallaSurvivor**’s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you're completely right.

The DFA that you have shown could also be written as follows. However, if this is for a class, you might want to double check with your professor just in case. As an undergrad I had a professor who would not let us use common abbreviations like these, even though they are used "in the wild" with little to no confusion.

[image: a simplified version of OP's DFA]

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thankyou ! Would  the non-deterministic version be the same as what you have drawn?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "the nondeterministic version". Every DFA is an NFA too, and so if you want to view this machine as nondeterministic, you can.

Comment: To be honest, I really don't know why your professor would not encourage you to use a notation which just adds clarity. At the same time, for some reason, people still prefer to write, for a DFA, $\delta(\delta(q,u),v) = \delta(q,uv)$ instead of the much simpler $(q\cdot u)\cdot v = q \cdot uv$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin - I was confused at the time, and I am equally confused now. Iirc, the justification was to make sure we properly understood what was happening before we "abused notation", but for an example like this it seems harmless ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. I remember losing points on it, and it haunts me to this day.